# Execute scripts through a FIFO QUEUE

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have different script executed by the crontab.

The crontab is like this:

```
 10,20,40,50 23,00-06 * * * /tmp/script1.bash
 0,30 * * * * /tmp/script1.bash
 */2 * * * * /tmp/script2.bash
```

I want to run the two script in a way that I'm sure that the other script is not running, so if the script1 is triggered the script2 has to wait for script1 to finish.

I can't use a wait for the other process to finish because it can cause a starvation...

I would like to find a way in which every time the cron is triggered it adds the script to a queue and then the scripts are executed sequentially.

Which is the best way using only bash?

Comment: At the moment I found a solution using flock and exclusive locking mechanism, it should assure a FIFO behavior in terms of execution

Answer (score 0):

At the moment I found a solution using flock and exclusive locking mechanism, it should assure a FIFO behavior in terms of execution – Kerby82